# What is happen when the number of file smaller than batch in HDF5

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a hdf5 layer that read the information from the list.txt as

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./list.txt"
    batch_size: 4
    shuffle: true
  }
}
```

where list.txt contains two path files

```
/home/user/file1.h5
/home/user/file2.h5
```

while the batch size is 4. What is happen with above code? Can the data choose 4 files to feed the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two hdf5 files, but each file may contain more than a single training example. Thus, effectively, you may have far more than `batch_size: 4` examples.

Caffe does not really cares about the actual number of training examples: when it finishes to process all the examples (aka "epoch") it simply starts over reading the samples again. Caffe cycles through all the samples until number of training/testing iteration is reached.

Comment: Thanks. My hdf5 contains one image. For example, 3D image.

Comment: then each batch would contain two copies of the two images. In this particular case I suppose setting `batch_size: 2` makes more sense. @user8264

Comment: Thanks. Because the data size is too big, so it needs to randomly crop a region in the image. Hence, I used batch size is 4. Although one file can choose twice times but the selected region may be different. Does it make sense?

Comment: @user8264 it is difficult to understand from your description, but if each sample is processed in a different way in the net than it might make sense to have two samples with batch_size: 4.